# aChartEngine; determining when a GraphicalView is fully rendered/drawn

Tags: android, achartengine

I've got a fragment, which I construct and insert a GraphicalView, and I need to know when the GraphicalView (chart) is done being drawn. the api isChartDrawn always returns false, including within onResume of the containing fragment.

```
public void onResume()
        {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume, the mChart isDrawn: " + mChart.isChartDrawn());
        super.onResume();
        mListener.didNotificyChartDrawn();
        }
```

Is there a notification I'm not seeing, or strategy for knowing when the chart is done being rendered? I'm asking because I need to access the series points from within one of the series of the XYChart used to construct the graphical view, like this:

```
 mChart = new GraphicalView(getActivity(), mXYChart);
```

where mXYChart is an instance of the LineChart.

The graph renders fine, and I'm able to access the points I need later on via touch handling, just need to get to them a little earlier now and am hitting this issue. Any work arounds, etc, appreciated.

Comment: it appears that isChartDrawn always returns false....forever

Comment: using a view tree observer isn't working, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're getting that because during `onResume` still was not draw yet. That's whole Android, not just aChartEngine. I'm not sure it's the best design decision, but that's how it is.

But good news is: there's a nice trick.

```
getView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(new OnDrawListener(){
    void onDraw(){
        getView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnDrawListener(this);
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

this trick is used A LOT for animation, so you can measure stuff on screen and do the proper animations.

Comment: damn... you comment that the ViewTreeObserver is not working on the same moment I sent my answer. You can try do a post: `getView().post(runnable);` inside the drawListener. That way the code will literally be called `AFTER` the thing have been draw on the screen.

Comment: haha! funny you mention that; that's exactly what I ended up doing. For now. I just realized that this only happens when I first draw the graph; updating it afterwards things work fine. Thanks for the reply @Budius I'll post back how I made out

Comment: I'm actually trying to render some things on a custom view, which overlays my graphical chart, and to make life a little easier, just using the getScreenPoint... method to get a path from all my series data points. When I redraw this path on my overlay, it's shifted from the line in my chart. weird; I'd think getScreenPoint would be literal screen points, but it looks like it's possibly accounting for padding/margin possibly, too. Onward

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `onDraw` method in GraphicalView, it sets the boolean `mDrawn` to true at the very end. So what must be happening is you are calling

```
public boolean isChartDrawn() {
    return mDrawn;
}
```

Before it has completed the onDraw method. I would either create a interval handler to keep checking if `mDrawn` has been changed to true, or modify the library file `GraphicalView` so that it has an optional listener that you can attach to be fired off when the thing is drawn:

```
DrawnInterface mCallback;

public interface DrawnInterface{
    public void onDrawn();
}


.....

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.getClipBounds(mRect);
     ......
       canvas.drawBitmap(fitZoomImage, left + width - zoomSize * 0.75f, buttonY, null);
     }
     mDrawn = true;
     mCallback.onDrawn();
}
```

Then make your calling activity implement the `DrawnInterface` you defined, and initialize the interface inside the constructor of `GraphicalView`